# MapPoint 2011 FindAddress dialog in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mappoint

I am adding a list of addresses into Mappoint using C#.

```
foreach (Stop stop in _stops)
                _route.Waypoints.Add(_mpMap.FindAddressResults(stop.Street, stop.City, "", "Oregon", stop.Zip)[1]);
```

Sometimes address format is wrong and because of that I get either crash or complected wrong address.

In mappoint (application) you can search for places and if mappoint finds multiple or you make a mistake in address, it opens a find and gives you options to search and/or add address anyway.

Example:
[image]

Notice how entered address is poorly formatted, but mapoint could easly find full address with normal formatting. Sometimes there are more results and I need to be able to select manually if that happens. Question: How?

**Added later on:**

I can call dialog itself with method `ShowFindDialog` and I can get the count of results found with .Count parameter

```
MapPoint.FindResults results = _mpMap.FindAddressResults(stop.Street, stop.City, "", "Oregon", stop.Zip);
MessageBox.Show("Found " + results.Count + " results");
```

But I can't find a way to specify address to `ShowFindDialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are abusing FindAddressResults. This does not return a simple array (which is how you are treating it), but a FindResults collection.
The FindResults collection includes a property called "ResultsQuality". This is fully documented in the help file that comes with MapPoint, but you **must** check this value before blindly assuming the collection contains one or more results!

The ResultsQuality property is set to a GeoFindResultsQuality enumeration. You want to check for geoAllResultsValid (0) or geoFirstResultGood (1). The other values indicate no results or ambiguus results.

Here's the VB6 example from the docs:

```
Sub AddPushpinToGoodFindMatch()

Dim objApp As New MapPoint.Application
Dim objFR As MapPoint.FindResults

'Set up the application
objApp.Visible = True
objApp.UserControl = True

'Get a FindResults collection
Set objFR = objApp.ActiveMap.FindResults("Seattle")

'If the first result is a good match, then use it
If objFR.ResultsQuality = geoFirstResultGood Then
    objApp.ActiveMap.AddPushpin objFR.Item(1)
Else
    MsgBox "The first result was not a good match."
End If

End Sub
```

FindResults() is an old method which returns the same FindResults class, but using FindAddressResults (as you are doing) is generally a much better thing to do.

---

Addenda: As this general problem is such a common problem (probably due to bad sample code in the MapPoint docs that is blindly cut&pasted), I've written an article about [using the FindResults collection correctly](http://www.mapping-tools.com/howto/programming/using-the-findresults-collection/), on my "MapPoint HowTo" pages.